# What is key difference between firebase "multicast" send and device group send?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know what is the key difference between firebase multicast send and device group send? What are the use cases where in we can use multicast send and device group send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device group can contain up to 20 separate device tokens. It is typically used for address a set of devices of the same user. Note that device groups are only exposed on the legacy API, and not in the newer versioned API of Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Multicast messaging can be used to send a message to 100-500 (depending on the platform) device tokens at a time. For an example of this, see [send messaging to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) and [sending a batch of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages) in the documentation.